# I found the boundary and it is closed, but I am not sure. Is there anyone who can help me?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Set is {($x_1,x_2$) $\in$ $R^2$ : $x_2 \neq 1$}. I called this set is A

Okey I found that int(set) = $\emptyset$ and boundary point is every point in this set. Therefore, I claimed that this is a closed set because A $\cap$ boundary point of A = A. I want to wonder that is my answer correct or not ?

Comment: Your set $A$ is actually open: it’s the set of all points not on the line $y=1$.

Comment: The interior of your set A would not be empty. but would have in it any point whose second coordinate is not $1$.

Comment: Ohh true i see the point. Hence, if set is  {($x_1,x_2$) $\in$ $R^2$ : $x_2 = 1$}, will it be closed because its interior points is empty and its boundary is all point in this set

Comment: and also what can I say for boundary points of this set Sir?

Comment: @SteveJosh: The boundary of $A$ is the set of all points that are in $\operatorname{cl}A\cap\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R^2\setminus A)$. You know that $\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R^2\setminus A)=\Bbb R^2\setminus A$; what is $\operatorname{cl}A$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I don't know what is expression of cl, but now I found that The boundary of A is {($x_1,x_2$) $\in R^2$ : $x_2 = 1$}; Is it correct Sir?

Comment: @SteveJosh: Yes, that’s correct.